# Sikuli: Java not found error

Tags: java, cmd, sikuli

While installing Sikuli, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\adb\Downloads>C:\Users\adb\Downloads\runSetup.cmd
'Files' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
+++ Java not found in standard places C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (x86)
+++ JAVA_HOME not specified
+++ ended with some errors
```

This occurs when I run the runSetup.cmd file.

I have installed both 32 and 64 bit versions of java and no other application seems to have a problem finding it (Like Minecraft and all Firefox application).

However, here are the locations of my Java installations:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25
```

Comment: Include the details of the error inline, not just through a link to a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `JAVA_HOME` as a system variable, and reference this on the Path.

- In windows, go to `computer > Computer properties > advanced system properties > Advanced > Environment variables`.
- Click on `New` under 'System Variables'.
- Give the variable `name` as `JAVA_HOME` and `value` as *path/to/java*.
- (For the `path/to/java` use the path to the Javascript Runtime Environment folder e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\` and not `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin`)
- Edit the variable `PATH` and add `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` at the end. Close and start your cmd again.
- Note that on some systems, there can be a maximum number of allowed characters in the path, so you may have to remove some entries from the path if you've exceeded the maximum. Do this with caution, and make a backup first (usually MS SQL Server entries are safe to delete)

Comment: After changing the variables and running it again, I get the error: JAVA_HOME specified but not usable

Comment: I had the same problem today which got fixed by specifying JAVA_HOME in the env variables. If this didn't fix your problem then sorry, I have no clue :(

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have added an edit to your answer that made your solution clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because Oracle has released a new version of Java. And the Sikuli install is looking for the 2 previes versions. (Current path for me is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40) I had the same problem with installing Sikuli on my new computer.

What I did is I modified the installation file, so that I can use it to install Sikuli on every new computer in my company. And to make sikuli recognize the latest Java version.

After modifing the "runSetup.cmd" you also need an adjusted "runIDE.cmd" for the IDE to recognize the latest Java version.

This is the adjusted code/file:

runSetup.cmd

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set SIKULIX_HOME=%~dp0
set PARMS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

if not defined JAVA_HOME goto CHECKJAVA
IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto JAVA_OK
echo +++ JAVA_HOME specified but not useable %JAVA_HOME%
echo +++ looking for Java in standard places

:CHECKJAVA
set PROGRAMS=%ProgramFiles%
if defined ProgramFiles(x86) set PROGRAMS32=%ProgramFiles(x86)%

IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre1.8.0_40" goto JAVA7
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre1.8.0_40
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA7
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre7" goto JAVA6
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre7
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA6
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre6" goto JAVANO
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre6
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVANO
if not defined %PROGRAMS32% goto JAVANO32

IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre1.8.0_40" goto JAVA7
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre1.8.0_40
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA7
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre7" goto JAVA6
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre7
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA6
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre6" goto JAVANO32
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre6
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVANO32
echo +++ Java not found in standard places %PROGRAMS% or %PROGRAMS32%
echo +++ JAVA_HOME not specified
goto STOPIT

:JAVA_OK 
echo +++ running this Java
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version
PATH=%SIKULIX_HOME%libs;%PATH%
echo +++ trying to start Sikuli Setup in %SIKULIX_HOME%
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" %PARMS% -jar "%SIKULIX_HOME%sikuli-setup.jar" %*

GOTO FINALLY
:STOPIT
echo.+++ ended with some errors
:FINALLY
ENDLOCAL
```

runIDE.cmd

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set SIKULIX_HOME=%~dp0
set PARMS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsikuli.FromCommandLine

if not defined JAVA_HOME goto CHECKJAVA
IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto JAVA_OK
echo +++ JAVA_HOME specified but not useable %JAVA_HOME%
echo +++ looking for Java in standard places

:CHECKJAVA
set PROGRAMS=%ProgramFiles%
if defined ProgramFiles(x86) set PROGRAMS32=%ProgramFiles(x86)%

IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre1.8.0_40" goto JAVA7
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre1.8.0_40
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA7
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre7" goto JAVA6
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre7
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA6
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre6" goto JAVANO
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre6
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVANO
if not defined %PROGRAMS32% goto JAVANO32

IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre1.8.0_40" goto JAVA7
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre1.8.0_40
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA7
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre7" goto JAVA6
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre7
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA6
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre6" goto JAVANO32
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre6
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVANO32
echo +++ Java not found in standard places %PROGRAMS% or %PROGRAMS32%
echo +++ JAVA_HOME not specified
goto STOPIT

:JAVA_OK 
echo +++ running this Java
set SIKULI_COMMAND=%*
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version
PATH=%SIKULIX_HOME%libs;%PATH%
echo +++ trying to start Sikuli IDE 
echo +++ using: %PARMS% -jar %SIKULIX_HOME%sikuli-ide.jar %SIKULI_COMMAND%
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" %PARMS% -jar "%SIKULIX_HOME%sikuli-ide.jar" %SIKULI_COMMAND%

GOTO FINALLY
:STOPIT
echo.+++ ended with some errors
:FINALLY
ENDLOCAL
```

If you for example 'right-click' on the file "runSetup.cmd" and choose 'Edit' you get to see the code. If you replace the 'original' code with my adjusted code it will be able to install using the latest Java version.

Answer (score 0):

For better compatibility, can try to download Java 7 32bit version, and set Java 7 installed path to Java Home environment variable. (if setup fail auto detection ).